# How can I tell whether Date & Time are "Set Automatically"?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, settings

How can I programmatically access whether the date and time are set automatically? This is set by the user in `Settings > General > Date & Time > Set Automatically`.

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to achieve here? Stopping your players from cheating by setting the time forward instead of waiting for an event?

Comment: Thanks, @Doc. That seems to answer my question... for the most part. It's rather unsatisfying not to have an official-API way to access this information.